# XAML reference static resource

Tags: xaml

How do I reference a staticresource in XAML? (I'm not talking about binding expressions..)
As in this example:

```
<csla:CslaDataProvider  
                       x:Key="Rekvisition"
                       ObjectType="{x:Type model.faktura.rekvisitioner:Rekvisition}"
                       FactoryMethod="NewRekvisition"

                       IsAsynchronous="False"
                       ManageObjectLifetime="True"
                       IsInitialLoadEnabled="False"
        >
            <csla:CslaDataProvider.FactoryParameters>
             <x:Array Type="ReadOnlyBruger">
               INSERT REFERENCE TO STATIC RESOURCE  
             </x:Array>
            </csla:CslaDataProvider.FactoryParameters>
        </csla:CslaDataProvider>
```

/Fredrik

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `StaticResourceExtension` with element syntax:

```
         <x:Array Type="ReadOnlyBruger">
           <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Rekvisition" />
         </x:Array>
```

Comment: This works! <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey=""> effectively inserts whatever the resource is into the xaml. (so if the resource is a DataTemplate then that line becomes the data template.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{StaticResource Rekvisition}` elsewhere in your xaml.

Comment: What else are you trying to assign it to?

Comment: Why can't you use an attribute for that?  `FactoryParameters="{StaticResource Rekvisition}"` should work - unless `FactoryParameters` is a collection property (which seems likely).  If that's the case, you'd need to know the details of the collection property to work out how to populate it correctly.